# Selector ":global" is not pure error with next js build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm migrating my current React project to Next.js. And I am getting an error saying

```sh
error - ./styles/base/_base.module.css:3:1
Syntax error: Selector ":global" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)
```

These are basically a few global styles that I use almost everywhere in the app plus a few browser resets. So I think it's a good idea to make these styles global. It used to work fine in my React app, but the Next build system is not okay with this. I found a solution on [github issues](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10142#issuecomment-648974042). The build system has stopped complaining after that, but it omits all my global styles now. Not sure what am I missing here.

Here is the link to my [next.config.js](https://github.com/iiison/reebelo-demo/blob/master/next.config.js) and [_app.js](https://github.com/iiison/reebelo-demo/blob/master/pages/_app.js)

It's been a long while, but I can't find what am I missing here.

Comment: @brc-dd nope, still not working.

Comment: While providing links is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question.